# miss hover event of div when selecting on droplist

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a div tag contain a droplist. That div slide from right to left when mouse hover, after div tag slided then i selecting on droplist then div tag auto slide to left. That occour only FireFox, IE.

This is link to test : http://jsfiddle.net/meoghe/DtYQL/54/

```
    function bindhover()
{
    $('#style-demo').hover(function() {
        }, function () {

            $(this).animate({
                            right: "-600px"
                        });
            //if(!$(".drlIndustry").is(":focus"))
           //{

            //}

        });
}
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#style-demo').find("a.close").hover(function () {
            $('#style-demo').animate({
                right: "-200px"
            });
        });

        bindhover();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If that has been your problem, try using `css3` either. `css3` is more reliable, less coding.

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/amostk/DtYQL/56/

Answer (score 0):

You should use mouseenter and mouseleave. But i would recommend using the CSS3 solution by [Stanley.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824227/3637034)

[JS Solution @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hBU3z/1/)

```
$(function() {

    var $styleDemo = $('#style-demo');
    var originalRight = $styleDemo.css('right');

    $styleDemo
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        console.log($styleDemo, originalRight);
        $styleDemo.animate({
            right: originalRight
        });
    })
    .on('mouseenter', function () {
        $styleDemo.stop(true).animate({
            right: "-200px"
        });
    });

});
```